# Python Zig Zag algorithm function not returning expected results

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, numpy

**Overview**

I am trying to use this Python Zig Zag candlestick indicator (utilises High,Low,Close values) on financial data but the code below appears to have a bug.

Is there another working Python module that provides this functionality?

**What is a Zig Zag indicator**

> The Zig Zag indicator plots points on the chart whenever prices reverse by a percentage greater than a pre-chosen variable.
>
> [Source](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/z/zig_zag_indicator.asp)

**What have I tried**

While searching for a Python zigzag indicator for candlestick charts the only code I could find was from this [pull request](http://#https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbn/ZigZag/2aa553bb23c86e3c22bccdf4cd67c515a24f5b45/zigzag/__init__.py).

```
def peak_valley_pivots_candlestick(close, high, low, up_thresh, down_thresh):
    """
    Finds the peaks and valleys of a series of HLC (open is not necessary).
    TR: This is modified peak_valley_pivots function in order to find peaks and valleys for OHLC.
    Parameters
    ----------
    close : This is series with closes prices.
    high : This is series with highs  prices.
    low : This is series with lows prices.
    up_thresh : The minimum relative change necessary to define a peak.
    down_thesh : The minimum relative change necessary to define a valley.
    Returns
    -------
    an array with 0 indicating no pivot and -1 and 1 indicating valley and peak
    respectively
    Using Pandas
    ------------
    For the most part, close, high and low may be a pandas series. However, the index must
    either be [0,n) or a DateTimeIndex. Why? This function does X[t] to access
    each element where t is in [0,n).
    The First and Last Elements
    ---------------------------
    The first and last elements are guaranteed to be annotated as peak or
    valley even if the segments formed do not have the necessary relative
    changes. This is a tradeoff between technical correctness and the
    propensity to make mistakes in data analysis. The possible mistake is
    ignoring data outside the fully realized segments, which may bias analysis.
    """
    if down_thresh > 0:
        raise ValueError('The down_thresh must be negative.')

    initial_pivot = _identify_initial_pivot(close, up_thresh, down_thresh)

    t_n = len(close)
    pivots = np.zeros(t_n, dtype='i1')
    pivots[0] = initial_pivot

    # Adding one to the relative change thresholds saves operations. Instead
    # of computing relative change at each point as x_j / x_i - 1, it is
    # computed as x_j / x_1. Then, this value is compared to the threshold + 1.
    # This saves (t_n - 1) subtractions.
    up_thresh += 1
    down_thresh += 1

    trend = -initial_pivot
    last_pivot_t = 0
    last_pivot_x = close[0]
    for t in range(1, len(close)):

        if trend == -1:
            x = low[t]
            r = x / last_pivot_x
            if r >= up_thresh:
                pivots[last_pivot_t] = trend
                trend = 1
                last_pivot_x = x
                last_pivot_t = t
            elif x < last_pivot_x:
                last_pivot_x = x
                last_pivot_t = t
        else:
            x = high[t]
            r = x / last_pivot_x
            if r <= down_thresh:
                pivots[last_pivot_t] = trend
                trend = -1
                last_pivot_x = x
                last_pivot_t = t
            elif x > last_pivot_x:
                last_pivot_x = x
                last_pivot_t = t


    if last_pivot_t == t_n-1:
        pivots[last_pivot_t] = trend
    elif pivots[t_n-1] == 0:
        pivots[t_n-1] = trend

    return pivots
```

**It can be utilised as follows:**

```
pivots = peak_valley_pivots_candlestick(df.Close, df.High, df.Low ,.01,-.01)
```

The `peak_valley_pivots_candlestick` function is almost working as expected but with the following data there appears to be a bug in how the Pivots are calculated.

**Data**

The data below is a slice from the complete data set.

```
dict1 = {'Date': {77: '2018-12-19',
  78: '2018-12-20',
  79: '2018-12-21',
  80: '2018-12-24',
  81: '2018-12-25',
  82: '2018-12-26',
  83: '2018-12-27',
  84: '2018-12-28',
  85: '2018-12-31',
  86: '2019-01-01',
  87: '2019-01-02',
  88: '2019-01-03',
  89: '2019-01-04',
  90: '2019-01-07',
  91: '2019-01-08',
  92: '2019-01-09',
  93: '2019-01-10',
  94: '2019-01-11',
  95: '2019-01-14',
  96: '2019-01-15',
  97: '2019-01-16',
  98: '2019-01-17',
  99: '2019-01-18',
  100: '2019-01-21',
  101: '2019-01-22',
  102: '2019-01-23',
  103: '2019-01-24',
  104: '2019-01-25',
  105: '2019-01-28',
  106: '2019-01-29',
  107: '2019-01-30',
  108: '2019-01-31',
  109: '2019-02-01',
  110: '2019-02-04',
  111: '2019-02-05'},
 'Open': {77: 1.2654544115066528,
  78: 1.2625147104263306,
  79: 1.266993522644043,
  80: 1.2650061845779421,
  81: 1.2712942361831665,
  82: 1.2689388990402222,
  83: 1.2648460865020752,
  84: 1.264606237411499,
  85: 1.2689228057861328,
  86: 1.275022268295288,
  87: 1.2752337455749512,
  88: 1.2518777847290041,
  89: 1.2628973722457886,
  90: 1.2732852697372437,
  91: 1.2786905765533447,
  92: 1.2738852500915527,
  93: 1.2799508571624756,
  94: 1.275835633277893,
  95: 1.2849836349487305,
  96: 1.2876144647598269,
  97: 1.287282943725586,
  98: 1.2884771823883057,
  99: 1.298296570777893,
  100: 1.2853471040725708,
  101: 1.2892745733261108,
  102: 1.2956725358963013,
  103: 1.308318257331848,
  104: 1.3112174272537231,
  105: 1.3207770586013794,
  106: 1.3159972429275513,
  107: 1.308061599731445,
  108: 1.311681866645813,
  109: 1.3109252452850342,
  110: 1.3078563213348389,
  111: 1.3030844926834106},
 'High': {77: 1.267909288406372,
  78: 1.2705351114273071,
  79: 1.269728422164917,
  80: 1.273658275604248,
  81: 1.277791976928711,
  82: 1.2719732522964478,
  83: 1.2671220302581787,
  84: 1.2700024843215942,
  85: 1.2813942432403564,
  86: 1.2756729125976562,
  87: 1.2773349285125732,
  88: 1.2638230323791504,
  89: 1.2739664316177368,
  90: 1.2787723541259766,
  91: 1.2792304754257202,
  92: 1.2802950143814087,
  93: 1.2801146507263184,
  94: 1.2837464809417725,
  95: 1.292774677276611,
  96: 1.2916558980941772,
  97: 1.2895737886428833,
  98: 1.2939958572387695,
  99: 1.299376368522644,
  100: 1.2910722494125366,
  101: 1.296714186668396,
  102: 1.3080273866653442,
  103: 1.3095861673355105,
  104: 1.3176618814468384,
  105: 1.3210039138793943,
  106: 1.3196616172790527,
  107: 1.311991572380066,
  108: 1.3160665035247805,
  109: 1.311475396156311,
  110: 1.3098777532577517,
  111: 1.3051422834396362},
 'Low': {77: 1.2608431577682495,
  78: 1.2615113258361816,
  79: 1.2633600234985352,
  80: 1.2636953592300415,
  81: 1.266784906387329,
  82: 1.266512155532837,
  83: 1.261877417564392,
  84: 1.2636473178863523,
  85: 1.268182635307312,
  86: 1.2714558839797974,
  87: 1.2584631443023682,
  88: 1.2518777847290041,
  89: 1.261781930923462,
  90: 1.2724264860153198,
  91: 1.2714881896972656,
  92: 1.271779179573059,
  93: 1.273058295249939,
  94: 1.2716660499572754,
  95: 1.2821005582809448,
  96: 1.2756240367889404,
  97: 1.2827255725860596,
  98: 1.2836146354675293,
  99: 1.2892080545425415,
  100: 1.2831699848175049,
  101: 1.2855949401855469,
  102: 1.2945822477340698,
  103: 1.301371693611145,
  104: 1.3063528537750244,
  105: 1.313870549201965,
  106: 1.313145875930786,
  107: 1.3058068752288818,
  108: 1.3101180791854858,
  109: 1.3045804500579834,
  110: 1.3042230606079102,
  111: 1.2929919958114624},
 'Close': {77: 1.2655024528503418,
  78: 1.262785792350769,
  79: 1.2669775485992432,
  80: 1.2648941278457642,
  81: 1.2710840702056885,
  82: 1.2688745260238647,
  83: 1.2648781538009644,
  84: 1.2646220922470093,
  85: 1.269357681274414,
  86: 1.2738043069839478,
  87: 1.2754288911819458,
  88: 1.2521913051605225,
  89: 1.2628813982009888,
  90: 1.2734960317611694,
  91: 1.278608798980713,
  92: 1.2737879753112793,
  93: 1.279967188835144,
  94: 1.2753963470458984,
  95: 1.2849836349487305,
  96: 1.2874983549118042,
  97: 1.2872166633605957,
  98: 1.28857684135437,
  99: 1.2983977794647217,
  100: 1.2853471040725708,
  101: 1.2891747951507568,
  102: 1.295773148536682,
  103: 1.308215618133545,
  104: 1.3121638298034668,
  105: 1.3208470344543457,
  106: 1.3160146474838257,
  107: 1.30804443359375,
  108: 1.3117163181304932,
  109: 1.3109424114227295,
  110: 1.3077365159988403,
  111: 1.3031013011932373},
 'Pivots': {77: 0,
  78: 0,
  79: 0,
  80: 0,
  81: 0,
  82: 0,
  83: 0,
  84: 0,
  85: 1,
  86: 0,
  87: 0,
  88: 0,
  89: -1,
  90: 0,
  91: 0,
  92: 0,
  93: 0,
  94: 0,
  95: 0,
  96: 0,
  97: 0,
  98: 0,
  99: 0,
  100: 0,
  101: 0,
  102: 0,
  103: 0,
  104: 0,
  105: 1,
  106: 0,
  107: 0,
  108: 0,
  109: 0,
  110: 0,
  111: 0},
 'Pivot Price': {77: nan,
  78: nan,
  79: nan,
  80: nan,
  81: nan,
  82: nan,
  83: nan,
  84: nan,
  85: 1.2813942432403564,
  86: nan,
  87: nan,
  88: nan,
  89: 1.261781930923462,
  90: nan,
  91: nan,
  92: nan,
  93: nan,
  94: nan,
  95: nan,
  96: nan,
  97: nan,
  98: nan,
  99: nan,
  100: nan,
  101: nan,
  102: nan,
  103: nan,
  104: nan,
  105: 1.3210039138793943,
  106: nan,
  107: nan,
  108: nan,
  109: nan,
  110: nan,
  111: nan}}
```

**Chart showing the issue**

`2019-01-03` should be the low pivot not `2019-01-04`

[image: issue chart]

**Code to show the issue in a chart:**

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],

                open=df['Open'],
                high=df['High'],
                low=df['Low'],
                close=df['Close'])])


df_diff = df['Pivot Price'].dropna().diff().copy()


fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(mode = "lines+markers",
        x=df['Date'],
        y=df["Pivot Price"]
    ))

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1000,
    height=800,)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['Pivot Price'].interpolate(),
                         mode = 'lines',
                         line = dict(color='black')))


def annot(value):
    if np.isnan(value):
        return ''
    else:
        return value
    

j = 0
for i, p in enumerate(df['Pivot Price']):
    if not np.isnan(p):

        
        fig.add_annotation(dict(font=dict(color='rgba(0,0,200,0.8)',size=12),
                                        x=df['Date'].iloc[i],
                                        y=p,
                                        showarrow=False,
                                        text=annot(round(abs(df_diff.iloc[j]),3)),
                                        textangle=0,
                                        xanchor='right',
                                        xref="x",
                                        yref="y"))
        j = j + 1
fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
fig.show()
```

**Generally the function works as can be seen in this chart.**

Edit.  This is the code I used to create the `Pivots` and `Pivot Price` cols.  Updating as per comment from @ands

`df['Pivots'] = pivots df.loc[df['Pivots'] == 1, 'Pivot Price'] = df.High df.loc[df['Pivots'] == -1, 'Pivot Price'] = df.Low`

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a small problem with `Pivot Price` column of `df`, your data set `for_so.csv` already contains column `Pivot Price` so you need to delete values in `df['Pivot Price']` and set it to new values based on `pivots`.

I have used the following code to create the correct `'Pivots'` and `'Pivot Price'` columns:

```
pivots = peak_valley_pivots_candlestick(df.Close, df.High, df.Low ,.01,-.01)
df['Pivots'] = pivots
df['Pivot Price'] = np.nan  # This line clears old pivot prices
df.loc[df['Pivots'] == 1, 'Pivot Price'] = df.High
df.loc[df['Pivots'] == -1, 'Pivot Price'] = df.Low
```

The main problem is with the zigzag code. Function `peak_valley_pivots_candlestick` has two small error. In for loop when condition `if r >= up_thresh:` is true then `last_pivot_x` is set to `x`, but it should be set to `high[t]`.

```
if r >= up_thresh:
    pivots[last_pivot_t] = trend#
    trend = 1
    #last_pivot_x = x
    last_pivot_x = high[t]
    last_pivot_t = t
```

It is the same with code in condition `if r <= down_thresh:` where `last_pivot_x` should be is set to `low[t]` instead of `x`.

```
if r <= down_thresh:
    pivots[last_pivot_t] = trend
    trend = -1
    #last_pivot_x = x
    last_pivot_x = low[t]
    last_pivot_t = t
```

And here is complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd


PEAK, VALLEY = 1, -1

def _identify_initial_pivot(X, up_thresh, down_thresh):
    """Quickly identify the X[0] as a peak or valley."""
    x_0 = X[0]
    max_x = x_0
    max_t = 0
    min_x = x_0
    min_t = 0
    up_thresh += 1
    down_thresh += 1

    for t in range(1, len(X)):
        x_t = X[t]

        if x_t / min_x >= up_thresh:
            return VALLEY if min_t == 0 else PEAK

        if x_t / max_x <= down_thresh:
            return PEAK if max_t == 0 else VALLEY

        if x_t > max_x:
            max_x = x_t
            max_t = t

        if x_t < min_x:
            min_x = x_t
            min_t = t

    t_n = len(X)-1
    return VALLEY if x_0 < X[t_n] else PEAK

def peak_valley_pivots_candlestick(close, high, low, up_thresh, down_thresh):
    """
    Finds the peaks and valleys of a series of HLC (open is not necessary).
    TR: This is modified peak_valley_pivots function in order to find peaks and valleys for OHLC.
    Parameters
    ----------
    close : This is series with closes prices.
    high : This is series with highs  prices.
    low : This is series with lows prices.
    up_thresh : The minimum relative change necessary to define a peak.
    down_thesh : The minimum relative change necessary to define a valley.
    Returns
    -------
    an array with 0 indicating no pivot and -1 and 1 indicating valley and peak
    respectively
    Using Pandas
    ------------
    For the most part, close, high and low may be a pandas series. However, the index must
    either be [0,n) or a DateTimeIndex. Why? This function does X[t] to access
    each element where t is in [0,n).
    The First and Last Elements
    ---------------------------
    The first and last elements are guaranteed to be annotated as peak or
    valley even if the segments formed do not have the necessary relative
    changes. This is a tradeoff between technical correctness and the
    propensity to make mistakes in data analysis. The possible mistake is
    ignoring data outside the fully realized segments, which may bias analysis.
    """
    if down_thresh > 0:
        raise ValueError('The down_thresh must be negative.')

    initial_pivot = _identify_initial_pivot(close, up_thresh, down_thresh)

    t_n = len(close)
    pivots = np.zeros(t_n, dtype='i1')
    pivots[0] = initial_pivot

    # Adding one to the relative change thresholds saves operations. Instead
    # of computing relative change at each point as x_j / x_i - 1, it is
    # computed as x_j / x_1. Then, this value is compared to the threshold + 1.
    # This saves (t_n - 1) subtractions.
    up_thresh += 1
    down_thresh += 1

    trend = -initial_pivot
    last_pivot_t = 0
    last_pivot_x = close[0]
    for t in range(1, len(close)):

        if trend == -1:
            x = low[t]
            r = x / last_pivot_x
            if r >= up_thresh:
                pivots[last_pivot_t] = trend#
                trend = 1
                #last_pivot_x = x
                last_pivot_x = high[t]
                last_pivot_t = t
            elif x < last_pivot_x:
                last_pivot_x = x
                last_pivot_t = t
        else:
            x = high[t]
            r = x / last_pivot_x
            if r <= down_thresh:
                pivots[last_pivot_t] = trend
                trend = -1
                #last_pivot_x = x
                last_pivot_x = low[t]
                last_pivot_t = t
            elif x > last_pivot_x:
                last_pivot_x = x
                last_pivot_t = t


    if last_pivot_t == t_n-1:
        pivots[last_pivot_t] = trend
    elif pivots[t_n-1] == 0:
        pivots[t_n-1] = trend

    return pivots


df = pd.read_csv('for_so.csv')



pivots = peak_valley_pivots_candlestick(df.Close, df.High, df.Low ,.01,-.01)
df['Pivots'] = pivots
df['Pivot Price'] = np.nan  # This line clears old pivot prices
df.loc[df['Pivots'] == 1, 'Pivot Price'] = df.High
df.loc[df['Pivots'] == -1, 'Pivot Price'] = df.Low



fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],

                open=df['Open'],
                high=df['High'],
                low=df['Low'],
                close=df['Close'])])


df_diff = df['Pivot Price'].dropna().diff().copy()


fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(mode = "lines+markers",
        x=df['Date'],
        y=df["Pivot Price"]
    ))

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1000,
    height=800,)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'],
                         y=df['Pivot Price'].interpolate(),
                         mode = 'lines',
                         line = dict(color='black')))


def annot(value):
    if np.isnan(value):
        return ''
    else:
        return value
    

j = 0
for i, p in enumerate(df['Pivot Price']):
    if not np.isnan(p):

        
        fig.add_annotation(dict(font=dict(color='rgba(0,0,200,0.8)',size=12),
                                        x=df['Date'].iloc[i],
                                        y=p,
                                        showarrow=False,
                                        text=annot(round(abs(df_diff.iloc[j]),3)),
                                        textangle=0,
                                        xanchor='right',
                                        xref="x",
                                        yref="y"))
        j = j + 1

        
fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
fig.show()
```

The code above produces this chart:

[image: Chart]

Comment: Thanks for this. I see you have set the index to `Datetime` for this slice of data which is a subset of my [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/navnkeqj59p1cjm/for_so.csv) When I try your suggested answer on the complete data the issue still remains where `2019-01-03` should be the low pivot not `2019-01-04`.

Comment: This is the code I used to create `Pivots` and `Pivot Price` and it returns the same result as your Lambda  `df['Pivots'] = pivots
df.loc[df['Pivots'] == 1, 'Pivot Price'] = df.High
df.loc[df['Pivots'] == -1, 'Pivot Price'] = df.Low`

Comment: Your code for setting `df['Pivots']` and `df['Pivot Price']` is correct, what might be wrong is the part where you create `pivots` (which is then copied to `df['Pivots']`), also `df` shouldn't contain column `Pivot Price` before setting `df['Pivot Price']` (so `dict1` shouldn't contain key `Pivot Price`, it is best if  `dict1` contains only `Date`, `Open`, `High`, `Low` and `Close`). Anyway, I have edited my answer and added complete code to produce the chart above.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear in my earlier answer but your solution did not fix the issue when I ran the code on the full [data set](https://www.dropbox.com/s/navnkeqj59p1cjm/for_so.csv) When I ran your code on the full data set the issue still remains where `2019-01-03` should be the low pivot not `2019-01-04`  I think its a problem with the zigzag code.  The dict I posted is only a subset and for some reason if you apply the zigzag algorithm to this subset it selects the correct low but not when applied to the full data set. If you test on the full data set I think you will see the issue.

Comment: You are right, I had only part of the data set so it seemed that it was working. There are two wrong lines in the zigzag code, I fixed that error, and the code should now work as expected.

Comment: Answer accepted.  Thank you for working through this with me, fixing the zigzag code and for sticking with it when the indicator appeared to work on the subset of data.  I had already identified the `last_pivot_x = low[t]` as a potential fix (but was not confident it was a valid change) but I did not identify the `last_pivot_x = high[t]` change (which I should have seen if I noted the other...) This working candlestick zigzag indicator should be useful for others who will find it here.

Comment: Thank you for this great idea, any idea why the last candle always shows pivots=1 ?

Comment: What do you mean that the last candle always shows pivots=1? Can you provide link to a image of the candle chart?